# using EntityFramework 6 with SQL Server Compact 4

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-ce

I am developping an application using Entity-Framework and Sql Server Compact 4 in a Visual Studio 2013 project.
Here is the list of add-ons I installed via NuGet :

- Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact 4.0.8876.1
- EntityFramework 6.1.3
- EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact 6.1.3

Then I want to add an ADO.NET Entity Data Model ("Code First from database").
I choose a sdf file that I already have created with SQL Server Compact Toolbox. The Wizard find it and generate a connection string

```
Data Source=E:\[...]\myDBtest.sdf
```

Then I click "Next >", the Wizard becomes gray, freezes a few seconds and then closes itself without showing the following step.
At the end, it did not generate anything into my project.

I tried to rebuilt the project before adding the ADO item.
And I even tried to reboot the computer ... with no more success.

Any suggestion or same experience ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can use Db First with EF and SQL Server Compact. In order to avoid the error, install the latest Visual Studio Tools for EF (6.1.3) https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762

Comment: It seems to work by installing these new tools. Note that I had to close VS2013 and restart it or EF did not link anymore to SQL Server compact. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are welcome! In order to install new VS tools, you must always restart VS, of course